# extjs6 stretch chart to fit screen vertically in hbox not working

Tags: extjs, layout, hbox

In my extjs6 layout, I want the chart to stretch to fit vertically the entire screen.  I thought changing the height of chart to 100% but it is not working.  Can someone please show me how to accomplish this?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2kkv&view/editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to subtract the height (36) of both the title bars **`title: 'TEST'`** and **`title: 'Bar Chart'`** from **`window.innerHeight`** and assign this height to **`chart`** like below:-

```
height: window.innerHeight - (36+36)
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2klp)